# Add value to array only if not already in, using bash

Tags: linux, bash

As I said the title. I tried this code:

```sh
    areasArray=()

    while IFS= read -r line
    do
        areaName="$(awk -F ";" '{print $3}')"
        echo $areaName

        if [[ ! " ${areasArray[@]} " =~ " $areaName " ]]; then
            areasArray+=($areaName)
            echo ${areasArray[*]}
        fi
    done < $reportFile
```

`$reportFile` refers to a CSV file that looks like this:

```
something;something;US
something;something;US
something;something;UK
something;something;FR
something;something;UK
something;something;FR
```

And the array will looks like this: `US US UK FR UK FR`. But I want every zone to be added **only if it's not already there**. So it should looks like this: `US UK FR`. How can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to perform lookup, use an associative array, not an indexed array. Basically, you'll use the keys of the associate array like a set.

```
declare -A areasArray

while IFS=";" read _ _ areaName _; do
    if [[ ! -v areasArray[$areaName] ]]; then
        areasArray[$areaName]=
    fi
done < "$reportFile"
```

Unless there is a specific action you want to take only if the key isn't already present, you can skip the `if`; `areasArray[$areaName]=` is idempotent.

Comment: I don't understand what ``areasArray[$areaName]=`` is supposed to do... How should I add my areas to my array, then?

Comment: It maps the area just read to an empty string. We aren't interested in the values associated with the keys, just the keys (areas) themselves. You can iterate over the areas later with something like `for area in "${!areasArray[@]}"; do ... ;done`.